# How to make all cross browser compatible skewed div edges?

Tags: html, css

There is a part of my website that uses skewed edges using the code:

-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 81% 100%, 0% 100%)

This works great in Chrome but does not work for any of the other major browsers.

See here: http://prntscr.com/carv7k

How can I achieve the effect I am going for using a cross compatible method? I know that I can use png however the user will have the ability to change the color of the divs meaning they must be CSS.

Comment: Unable to see the picture. Also, please post your code. Have you thought about using SVG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link of the screenshot is not working :/

Anyway you can use before & after elements with the css triangle method:

```
div {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -20px;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -20px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0r3n9vev/

Comment: Was perfect for my problem. So easy to integrate and cross browser support. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with other browsers, add an additional CSS rule after the one you have defined, but with "-webkit-" removed. So:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 81% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 81% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

Note, however, that [support for this feature is minimal](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) and highly experimental, if not nonexistent.